# Mod_Rewrite Redirect

Tags: html, mod-rewrite, redirect, http-status-code-301

I'm having a problem with mod_rewrite on my hosting. All is working fine, but I changed my directories organization and so now all pages Google indexed before the change have the wrong extension (I decided to add a .html at the end of the name, now urls look like "www.mydomain.com/page_name/details_on_page/page_id/name_of_resource.html" while before it was like "www.mydomain.com/page_name/details_on_page/page_id/name_of_resource") and return a 404 error.

How could I write a mod_rewrite COND and then a rule to redirect 301 page with missing html extension to the .html page?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.html$
RewriteRule ^page_name/(.+)$ /page_name/$1.html [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Never thought to receive such a good answer in a short time.